# Transaction pending in queue for 100mins +

Tags: parity, pending-transactions, parity-wallet

Using Parity I submitted at Transfer of ETH using 'send after block'
The transaction has now been pending for 100mins+ (see attached).[image]
Now I can't send any ETH as all transactions go into 'Pending' state.

How to I either get these transactions to execute or remove them ?

Many thanks in advance

[UPDATE] at 20170621-1901 =

Rebooted my Mac restarted Parity via Chrome browser result = the 2 existing transactions have been posted again 20mins ago, propagated to 50+ peers and still they are pending. There is something else at play here ...

Can someone PLEASE tell me how I can remove these transactions ?
Looks to me as if they are just being ignored by the Miners ?

Answer (score 6):

The network's under strain cause of the Status ICO. Unfortunately there's not much you can do for cancelling it since the transaction has already been propagated to other nodes.

If you click on the Gas Price you can set a higher price and resubmit the transaction to the network.

Comment: Do you have a view on the fact that these transactions cannot be found on etherscan ? i.e. 0x5d52f62f77312c0d14dc5cc7ee58ba53fdc51279fe7e022a7276f3f9c443bbb5 ?

Comment: It's merely because your not near the top of the queue of the etherscan.io node. If you're using parity, go to "applications -> txqueue viewer" to verify you're just backlogged from an ICO / etc going on. If you see your transaction you're all set, just wait it out.

Comment: How long do I need to wait ? Its around 20 hours now and I cannot use the ETH in this wallet !

Answer (score -3):

I found the following statement on their facebook:

"Guys, #Ethereum and all based tokens are temporarily unavailable. Transactions with those may fail. Keep calm, we're dealing with it. You will get your coins within 24 hours, once the issue is resolved. Don't hesitate to PM us, if you have any questions."

Update: Sorry, this concerns "Chanelly" and not Ethereum itself.
Maybe it concerns the same issue.